# VS 2022 Unable To Find .NET 4.8

Tags: .net, windows-10, visual-studio-2022

I updated from VS 2019 to VS 2022 on my Windows 10 machine and am now unable to load up projects. On load, it complains that the referenced .NET version is not installed (it is), and if I choose "upgrade," it complains that the reference assemblies cannot be found. I have tried setting the PATH variable to the dotnet installation location (D:\Program Files\dotnet), have reinstalled and repaired 4.8 and 4.7 multiple times. Using dotnet --info indicates that only core 5 and 6 are installed, but I have no idea where the other versions might be located.

[image: VS Installer view]

[image: Build output]

[image: Environment variables]

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the folder for x 64 assemblies `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework` and for x86 under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework
```

When I uninstalled my VS 2022 Preview, I had issues with .NET Core 3.1 was not recognized, although I had the x64 version installed. When I installed the x86 version, the issue was resolved for me.
I have also repaired my VS 2019 but it does not solved the issue.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb3644?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed