# Visual Studio keep asking me to update to 4.8 .NET framework when its already installed . How do i fix this problem?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, window, .net-4.8

- Already installed .NET framework 4.8 using the vs installer
- I also check registry
- Manually download and installed the .NET framework 4.8.1 but the issue is still not fix. :c

### IM using VS 2022 in windows 11

[image: as you can see i already installed .NET framework 4.8 using the vs installer]

---

I also check registry and it's there

[image: I also check registry and it's there]

---

And when i'm creating a new project and selecting 4.8 .NET framework, its not there in drop down option

Its **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**

[image: And when i'm creating a new project and selecting 4.8 .NET framework, its not there in drop down option]

---

Programs and feature in control panel is already on
But its not showing up in installed list tho.

[image: Programs and feature in control panel is already on]

---

I manually download the 4.8.NET Framework dev pack in this site: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net48
and successfully installed and yet its not appearing in "programs and features" in control panel.

Can someone help me out. sorry for my bad english. hopefully i explain it enough

Comment: If the .net framework is not installed directly through Visual Studio Installer, the paths are often inconsistent. At this time, check the dotnet path in the environment variable and install the undetected .net framework to the dontnet path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer here: [VS 2022 Unable To Find .NET 4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70318786/vs-2022-unable-to-find-net-4-8)

its already installed. just in wrong path so i copy the already installed files of .net framework and pasted in **D:**